# What possibilities are around to debug Cordova apps (with native plugins)?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, debugging

I am trying to debug a Cordova app that makes use of native plugins (for authentication, API access etc.). Therefore the app does not run from the browser/Ripple.

I am using Visual Studio Tool for Apache Cordova (TACO) now to emulate and put breakpoints/watches and single step through the code to debug. I am wondering if there are any good alternatives to single step through the code for Cordova apps with platform specific plugins.

It would be nice if it was possible to debug without relying in Visual Studio while developing. Are there solutions for this that work with other IDEs?

Comment: Two links to get you started: [Chrome inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en) for debugging Android devices and [Teleriks summary](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-concise-guide-to-remote-debugging-on-ios-android-and-windows-phone/) on remote debugging, also including debugging iOS devices....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug Android native code in Android Studio, iOS code - in XCode (on OSX).
Windows plugins code is best to debug in Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Code editor is handy to debugging the app (js) code (it also supports livereload if you have Ionic installed).

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing on android while you're device is connected through ADB you can go on chrome://inspect on a new tab in chrome. When cordova app is running you can select inspect and debug like a web page your running app.

Comment: I target Windows Phone devices, iOS devices and Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug platform specific Plugin code then you have to use Visual Studio, Android Studio for sure.. Don't know about iOS..